# How get all selected option value ids in single onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

In an php, we can use select option in that a user can select more than one option value, after that i click the move button, a on-click function is wrote in button, now how can i get all selected option value in single onclick.

```
 <button type="button" id="search_rightSelected" onclick="inventory_left_to_right(document.getElementById('search'),false)" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

 <select id="search" multiple>
   <option value="1">Volvo</option>
   <option value="2">Saab</option>
   <option value="3">Opel</option>
   <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select> 

<button type="button" id="search_rightSelected" onclick="inventory_left_to_right()" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> HHH </button>

<script>

function inventory_left_to_right() {
    //var allVal = '';
    var allValArr = [];
    $("#search :selected").each(function() {
       // you can use to get the values $(this).val();
       //allVal += $(this).val()+',';
       allValArr.push($(this).val());
    });
    //allVal = allVal.substring(0, allVal.length - 1);
    console.log(allValArr);
}
</script>
```

Comment: you shouldn't ask other user to send you full code.

Comment: in an button i'm using like this  onclick="inventory_left_to_right(this.value)"

Comment: function inventory_left_to_right (a) {
   $("#search option").each(function() {
    alert(a);
   });
}

Comment: nw wt can i do @ABDUL

Comment: @karnaGowtham, Actually how to get you selected value string or array? I have given as string value.

Comment: @ABDUL i want like an array, i'm using in ajax process after onclick

Comment: I gave as an array. check it please @KarnaGowtham

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106979/discussion-between-karnagowtham-and-md-abdul-halim).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [DEMO](http://marcgrabanski.com/jquery-select-list-values/)

```
$('#search_rightSelected').click(function() {
     var foo = []; 
     $('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
     foo[i] = $(selected).text(); 
   });
});
```

OR

the val function called from the select will return an array if its a multiple. `$('select#search_rightSelected').val()` will return an array of the values for the selected options - you dont need to loop through and get them yourself.

Comment: sorry krishan in that demo we can choose only one value